# Index is not refreshing the data in Solr search

Tags: php, apache, solr, dataimporthandler

I am new to solr search. I have installed it successfully and when I wrote my database query in `data-config.xml` and run the URL on web browser then it responded the correct result. But now when I make some changes in the database query and refresh the browser then it does not change the result even if my query is correct. I have also tried restarting solr without success. I am using jetty for solr.

Comment: did you **run** a full or delta import?

Answer (score 0):

In case you have done a delta import which is done for updating the indexes see if you have the changes commited.